# jQuery select checkbox by clicking parent div and limit selection to 3

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

Hi I found the solution on stackoverflow to select the check-box by clicking the parent div however I am looking for a solution to limit the selection to 3. I found the solution separately for limiting the checkbox selection but not able to merge both solutions.

Please note that my checkboxes will be invisible and user can make selection by clicking on div. But I need to limit this selection to 3.

```
<form role="form">

    <div class="question">I’m Looking For / To:</div>
    <div class="imageContainer" id="question-container-1">
    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text">
        <label for="id_1">Label1</label>
        <div class="l-right">
            <input id="id_1" type="checkbox" name="id_1" value="Label1">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="imageContainer" id="question-container-2">
    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text">
        <label for="id_2">Label2</label>
        <div class="l-right">
            <input id="id_2" type="checkbox" name="id_2" value="Label1">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="imageContainer" id="question-container-3">
    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text">
        <label for="id_3">Label3</label>
        <div class="l-right">
            <input id="id_3" type="checkbox" name="id_3" value="Label1">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

     <div class="imageContainer" id="question-container-4">
    <img src="bg.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text">
        <label for="id_4">Label4</label>
        <div class="l-right">
            <input id="id_4" type="checkbox" name="id_4" value="Label1">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

here are the jquery -

```
 jQuery(function(){

// required for image checkboxes    
    jQuery('.imageContainer input:checkbox,.imageContainer label').bind("click",function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
   jQuery("div.imageContainer input:checkbox").bind("click",function(){
      var imageContainerDiv = jQuery(this).closest("div.imageContainer");
      var imageContainerInput = jQuery(this);
      var triggerEl="";
      imageContainer(imageContainerDiv,triggerEl);
   });
   jQuery("div.imageContainer").bind("click",function(){
      var imageContainerDiv = jQuery(this);
      var triggerEl=imageContainerDiv;
      imageContainer(imageContainerDiv,triggerEl);
   });



 function imageContainer(imageContainerDiv,triggerElement){
      var imageContainer=jQuery(imageContainerDiv).children("input:checkbox");
      var imageCheckbox = jQuery(imageContainerDiv).find("input");
      if(triggerElement==imageContainerDiv){
         imageCheckbox.prop("checked", !imageCheckbox.prop("checked"));
      }
      jQuery(imageContainerDiv).toggleClass("ic-checked");
      jQuery(imageContainerDiv).find("label").toggleClass("ic-selected");
   }

//script required to limit only 3 checkbox to be selected.      
 var max = 3;
    var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.change(function(){
        var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
    });
 });
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6R2Ep/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo-code for what it sounds like you need:

1. A click event on the Div/picture occurs
2. Detect number of checkbox's checked
3. If checkbox's checked equals 3, loop through all checkbox's and add the DISABLED attribute to all non-checked boxes
4. If checkbox's is less than 3, loop through all checkbox's and remove the DISABLED attribute

Comment: thanks @ejc. I tried to implement the steps but still unable to deselect the options by clicking on the image. also I want to disable other options at the moment the 3rd option is selected. any suggestions? here is the updated fiddle[link](http://jsfiddle.net/6R2Ep/4/)